# inheritance of private member variable from class template

Tags: c++

I made a class template looks like below, as base class for other classes to inherit from, and it would work fine as expected.

But my question is, The code still compiles even if I change 'protected' of class 'Operation' to 'private', even Matmul(which inherits class 'Operation') is modifying vector called 'edgeIn' which is declared as 'private'.

I can't understand why something like this should be allowed...
Shouldn't compiler trigger error message on this? (derived class shouldn't modify private member of base class)

```
template<typename T>
class Operation{
private: //Would compile fine even if I change this to 'private!'
    class edge{
    public:
        edge(Tensor<T> tensor, Operation<T> &from, Operation<T> &to) {
            this->tensor = tensor;
            this->from = from;
            this->to = to;
        }
        Operation<T> from;
        Operation<T> to;
        Tensor<T> tensor;
    };
    std::vector<edge> edgeIn; //edges as inputs of this operation
    std::vector<edge> edgeOut; //edges as outputs of this operation
private:
    //disable copy constructor (NOT ALLOWED)
    Operation(Operation<T>& rhs) = default;
    //disable move operator (NOT ALLOWED)
    Operation<T>& operator=(Operation<T> &rhs) = default;
    int operationId;
};

template<typename T>
class Matmul: public Operation<T>{
public:
    Matmul(std::initializer_list<std::pair<Tensor<T>, Operation<T>>> args);
};

template<typename T>
//from Operation<T>, to This operation
Matmul<T>::Matmul(std::initializer_list<std::pair<Tensor<T>, Operation<T>>> args){
    for(auto elem: args){
        typename Operation<T>::edge info{elem.first, elem.second, *this};
        this->edgeIn.emplace_back(info); //modifying member of base class
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an instantiation of that template class?

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. Templates are not compiled, unless necessary (there exists an instantiation of it).

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius -- templates are partially compiled. The issue here **probably** is that until the template is instantiated (say, as `Matmul<float>`), the compiler doesn't know for sure that `edge` is private; there could be a specialization `Operation<float>` with a public type named `edge`. You're right, of course, that a complete example is needed.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yes, I know that they are somewhat compiled (at the very least - the syntax of the code is checked). But, since I wasn't sure how to express that in a short, and concise, way, I decided to leave the comment as-is, since it wasn't the main point of the comment (which was: [mcve] request).

Answer (score 1):

In the code you've shown, it's allowed because it's not wrong. Here's a simpler example:

```
template <class Ty>
class base {
    int i; // private
};

template <class Ty>
class derived : base {
    void set(int ii) { i = ii; }
};
```

At this point, if you write

```
derived<int> di;
di.set(3); // illegal: i is not accessible
```

you'll get an access error, as you expect.

But the original template isn't wrong, because the code might do this:

```
template <>
class base<int> {
public:
    int i;
};
```

Now you can write

```
derived<int> di;
di.set(3);
```

and it's okay, because `i` is public in `base<int>`. You still can't write

```
derived<double> dd;
dd.set(3); // illegal: i is not accessible
```

Comment: _"it's allowed because it's not wrong"_ Best quote ever!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and Sorry for not providing complete example.. I thought compiler should tell me if there is any attempt modifying base class's private member( even it's only in class template). It turns out that you were right. Compiler would complain if I instantiate the code written in 'private'.